# Stored Procedure Issue in Simple Select Statement Issue in Varchar

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, procedure

Here is my  [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cb69)

**Here is My Table :**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vehicle` (
  `AutoID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `VehicleCode` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `NumberSeats` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `VehicleNumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `MaximumAllowed` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `State` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Insurance` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `VehicleType` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Tax` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `InsurancePhoto` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `RCPhoto` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CreatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `UpdatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `UpdatedBy` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ActiveStatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `IsDeletable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AutoID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `VehicleCode` (`VehicleCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

**And Inserted two Records**

```
INSERT INTO `vehicle` (`AutoID`, `VehicleCode`, `NumberSeats`, `VehicleNumber`, `MaximumAllowed`, `City`, `State`, `Phone`, `Insurance`, `VehicleType`, `Address`, `Tax`, `InsurancePhoto`, `RCPhoto`, `CreatedAt`, `CreatedBy`, `UpdatedAt`, `UpdatedBy`, `ActiveStatus`, `IsDeletable`) VALUES
(1, '100', 0, '', 0, '', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', 0, 0),
(2, '101', 0, '', 0, '', '', NULL, '', '', '', '', '', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', 0, 0);
```

I can able to Select the Records using Regular Select Statement

```
SELECT * FROM `vehicle` where VehicleCode = '100'
```

I Created the Procedure to Select

**My Procedure is Here**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetVehicle(IN VCode VARCHAR(20))
 BEGIN
 SELECT * 
 FROM vehicle
 WHERE VehicleCode = VCode;
 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

While i try to access my Procedure , i am not getting any result.

```
CALL `GetVehicle`(100);
```

I am not getting any result.

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i fix it ??

Comment: Try [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d8286/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing VehicleCode in

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetVehicle(IN Vcode VARCHAR(255))
```

to Vcode and then use it in the where statement.

Comment: TO be precise it should be something as `CREATE PROCEDURE GetVehicle(IN v_code VARCHAR(255))` and use `v_code` in where condition.

Comment: Thanks, I modified VehicleCode to VCode But while i call CALL `GetVehicle`(101) i am not getting any result

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty you are right. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: @Stackerman, just to clarify, in your question you indicate you call 100, does 100 works now but not 101? Also, when you select * from vehicle do you get the results that are with the IDs you are providing?

Comment: 100 or 101 that is just the Parameter, The Issue is Not returning any result while i use the Query **CALL GetVehicle(100)** or **CALL GetVehicle(101)** Yes i am Getting the result for SELECT * FROM `vehicle` WHERE VehicleCode = '100'

Comment: @Stackerman and you have these data in your vehicle table. Can you update your post with sample data after you select * from vehicle?

Comment: According to the definition of the table `Vcode` should be defined as `VARCHAR(20)`.

Comment: Yes, i have updated the question, kindly check above

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code it's fine but you should insert records to your schema and change your stored parameter name to be different than field name, you can name it "vcode" for example

so your schema should be

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vehicle` (
  `AutoID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `VehicleCode` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `NumberSeats` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `VehicleNumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `MaximumAllowed` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `State` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Insurance` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `VehicleType` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Tax` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `InsurancePhoto` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `RCPhoto` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CreatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `UpdatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `UpdatedBy` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ActiveStatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `IsDeletable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AutoID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `VehicleCode` (`VehicleCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

insert into vehicle(VehicleCode,NumberSeats,VehicleNumber,MaximumAllowed,
                    City,State,Phone,Insurance,VehicleType,Address,Tax,
                   InsurancePhoto,RCPhoto,CreatedAt,CreatedBy,UpdatedAt,
                   UpdatedBy,ActiveStatus,IsDeletable) 
                   values('100',4,'DES547',7,'Los','CA',44554,'45879','sedan',
                          'ssssss','55', 'sdsdsds','asdasdas',Now(),'saasda',
                           Now(),'asdasda',1,1);
```

then create your stored procedure as the following

```
DELIMITER //
create PROCEDURE GetVehicle(IN vcode VARCHAR(255))
 BEGIN
 SELECT * 
 FROM vehicle
 WHERE VehicleCode = vcode;
 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

now try to call the stored procedure it will work fine with you

```
call GetVehicle(100);
```

Comment: I did the same, i am trying in it phpmyadmin, will that be an issue ?

Comment: i tried it in mysql workbench and it is working fine try to call procedure like this CALL GetVehicle('100'); and tell me the result

Comment: Its working from the query via php , but not in the phpmyadmin

Comment: how you run the procedure from phpmyadmin? try to run the procedure  from left pane go to your database name expand it and fine prcedures and expand it click on "GetVehicle" procedure, execute routine window will appear write "100" in value field and press go the result should appear to you